# Jersey client - Acces Control Exception: java.security.AccessControlException Access denied

Tags: java, jersey, deploying

I am trying to access an api on a server. I am using jersey with java 1.6.

I have two environment with the same java version 1.6.

On the first everything works perfectly!

On the second (where I need to deploy the application) I have an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (
java.security.AllPermission <all permissions> <all actions>)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:
108)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:533)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$9.run(URLClassLoader.java:924)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224
)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.getPermissions(URLClassLoader.java:922)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getPD(SecureClassLoader.java:101)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69
)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:529)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:440)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:68)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1027)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284
)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:660)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
        at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before or might know how to resolve it?